# JavaScript Session and Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, session

Does Magento 2 allow JavaScript session storage?

Description:  Actually, I want to store data inside the session of JS and utilize it in other phtml files which are actually replacing the previous one.
For example, I have phtml1 and phtml2, I am replacing phtml1 by phtml2 but I want to use some value from phtml1 in phtml2 for which I am using JAVASCRIPT session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, session storage is nothing to do with Magento as it is core browser functionality.

Comment: thankx Ben Crook